# The convolution on a semisimple finite quantum groupoid

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras, fusion-categories

Let $\mathbb{A}$ be a finite  dim. **weak**  Hopf $C^*$-algebra (or semisimple finite quantum groupoid) and $\hat{\mathbb{A}}$ its dual.
Let the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}: \mathbb{A} \to \hat{\mathbb{A}}$ and the convolution $a * b = \mathcal{F^{-1}}(\mathcal{F}(a).\mathcal{F}(b))$.
As an algebra, $\mathbb{A}$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of matrix algebras. Let $B = \{b_1, \dots , b_n  \}$ a matrix basis.

Let the structure constants $(c^{\gamma}_{\alpha \beta})$ and $(d^{\gamma}_{\alpha \beta})$  of the comultiplication $\Delta$ and the convolution product $*$ given by $\Delta(b_{\gamma}) = \sum_{\alpha \beta} c^{\gamma}_{\alpha \beta} . b_{\alpha} \otimes b_{\beta}$ and $b_\alpha*b_\beta= \sum_\gamma {d}_{\alpha\beta}^\gamma b_\gamma$.

**Question**: Is $d^{\gamma}_{\alpha \beta} = \delta \overline{c^{\gamma}_{\alpha \beta}}$?
[with $\delta = dim(\mathbb{A})^{1/2}$]

*Remark*: See proposition 8.16 p40 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.06649v7.pdf) for a proof in the non-weak case.

---

There is the following definition of the Fourier transform in the planar algebra framework, *but I guess there is an equivalent definition in the Hopf algebra framework*.

A finite dimensional weak Hopf $C^*$algebra is by definition a finite dimensional weak Kac algebra.
If we consider the finite index depth $2$ subfactor planar algebra $\mathcal{P} = \mathcal{P}(R \subset R\rtimes \mathbb{A})$, with $R$ the hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$ factor, then $\mathbb{A}$ and $\hat{\mathbb{A}}$ are the $2$-boxes algebras $\mathcal{P}_{2,+}$ and $\mathcal{P}_{2,-}$.
The Fourier transform $\mathcal{F} : \mathcal{P}_{2,\pm} \to \mathcal{P}_{2,\mp}$ is the $1$-click rotation (see for example [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.1165v1.pdf) p9).

Comment: Could I ask how do you define the Fourier Transform and if yes how do you define the Fourier Transform?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: see the edit.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: your comment seems said that there is no definition for the Fourier transform in the general weak Hopf C*-algebra framework, isn't it?

Comment: Having worked on this problem would you have any insight into this problem: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234332/quantum-group-representations-from-convolution-matrix-units

Comment: So there is no more explicit expression for the Fourier transform? I mean, without alluding to anything infinite-dimensional?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: in the planar algebra framework, the Fourier transform is just the $1$-click rotation in the $2$-box space $\mathcal{P}_{2,\pm}$, which is finite dimensional [more precisely, $\mathcal{P}_{2,+} = \mathbb{A}$ and $\mathcal{P}_{2,-} = \hat{\mathbb{A}}$]. It is not necessary to use the hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$ factor to define the planar algebra of a finite dimensional Kac algebra, everything can be done algebraically and finite dimensionally (see https://www.imsc.res.in/~sunder/paha.pdf)

Comment: Excuse me but (at least for me) extracting the needed expression from that text (I guess you mean (5.33) and (5.34) there), or also from the text linked to in the question, purely in terms of $\mathbb A$ is quite a nontrivial task, so it would make your question much more accessible (at least for me) if you could just give a formula for $\cal F$ explicitly - say, in terms of the $b_i$s.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I didn't find in the literature a definition of a Fourier transform for a finite dimensional weak Hopf algebra $\mathbb{A}$, purely in term of  $\mathbb{A}$, but it is very natural in the planar algebra framework (diagrammatically it is just a 90° rotation). I don't know also how to translate this planar algebraic definition purely in term of $\mathbb{A}$, and it is not clear that it's possible (easily). The planar algebra framework is very adapted for the Fourier transform, so my advice could be to work directly in this framework.

Comment: There is a nice series of smooth lectures introducing to the planar algebras, see [this link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjudt2gd3iAe40juwS3dKocAoooXF91Vi).